# Java 6 json parsing

Tags: java, json

I've been using org.json for all my parsing needs in the past but now I'm deploying to a websphere application server v 7.0.0.22 which runs java 6 and I'm seeing unsupported exceptions indicating the org.json library is not supported there. Are there any other good json parsing library's that can be used with java version 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackson is good, but you can also use Google Gson :

https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Oh right, I used Gson on a previous project years ago and it was good.

Comment: Yeap that did the trick. Very nice api and auto mapping. Jackson looks like it would have worked to but i can only check one answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In my current job, we use Jackson from codehouse. We don't have any concerns with it, works very well on our environment. We use jboss instead of websphere though

http://jackson.codehaus.org/